# Getting a set attribute in a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I have an attribute which is is set in a jsp page and would like to know how this is called in a java program and how this would be used in that program (e.g. as a string in a class)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to convert it to a List and then pass it through.

You can use List.addAll() function.

```
Set yourSet = new HashSet();

List yourList = new ArrayList();

yourList.addAll(yourSet);

return yourList;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%request.getAttribute("attrubuteName")%>
```

use scriptlets in you jsp page and access the attributes using request object.